# How to re enable the default MIDI synth in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, midi

I installed some time ago [VirtualMIDISynth](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth) to have soundfont-able MIDI reproducing in my machine. But soon I began to realize how incompatible with players and MIDI editors this jury-rig-type of software was.

After finally learning about Timidity++ player/converter, I uninstalled this driver, only to find MS GS wavetable (or the default midi synth) now is missing on programs like AnvilStudio and Windows Media Player (Windows Media Player throws [error C00D11BA](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/c00d11ba)).

How can I re-enable the default MIDI synth?

Comment: I seemed to be having a similar issue with the default Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth not functioning properly. Within the past week or so, it seems that the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth has begun functioning properly again. It is difficult to say what may have caused it to begin working again, but I suspect [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3143146) update or [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3139907) update. Still, neither mentions any fix involving MIDI or (in the case of the latter update) winmm.dll, which is evidently responsible for the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth.

Comment: Good news is the updated versions work a lot better. Windows upgrades still play havoc with them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions on [VirtualMidiSynth's website](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth/faq#faq12), specifically under the `Default MIDI output device configurations`section explain how to re-enable the default MIDI synth.

> **Folders to delete:**
>
> - C:\Windows\System32\VirtualMIDISynth
> - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\VirtualMIDISynt (only on 64bit systems)
>
> **Registry keys to delete:**
>
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CoolSoft VirtualMIDISynth
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\CoolSoft VirtualMIDISynth **(only on 64bit systems)**
>
> **Registry keys to edit:**
>
> These keys contain the registered multimedia drivers on the system. To
>   reset the registry to default state, set all **midi*** subkeys (midi,
>   midi1, midi2, ..., midi9) values to **wdmaud.drv**.
>
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32 **(only on 64bit systems)**
>
> **Default MIDI output device configurations:**
>
> The following keys contains the default MIDI device configured for
>   MidiMapper (up to Windows 7 included) and Windows Media Player. 
>   **NOTE**: if WMP keys are missing they will be recreated at next Windows Media Player configuration change / close / reopen.
>
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\MIDIMap --> szPname = Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth **(up to Windows 7 included)**
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ActiveMovie\devenum{4EFE2452-168A-11D1-BC76-00C04FB9453B}\Default MidiOut Device --> MidiOutId = FFFFFFFF
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ActiveMovie\devenum
>     64-bit{4EFE2452-168A-11D1-BC76-00C04FB9453B}\Default MidiOut Device --> MidiOutId = FFFFFFFF **(only on 64bit systems)**

Comment: There's a script for it [here](https://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/forum/post/2910#post2910), unfortunately there is another issue on 1809 causing WMP not to play the midi files.

Comment: The "other issue" was the reboot required for the system + `wdmaud.drv` to acclimatize themselves with the adjusted settings.

Answer (score 1):

For resetting Windows registry I simply use the below text file (renamed from `.txt` to `.reg`) and double click it and it puts MIDI mapping back to default.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32]
"midi"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi1"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi2"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi3"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi4"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi5"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi6"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi7"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi8"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer1"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer3"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer4"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer5"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer6"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer7"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer8"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave1"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave3"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave4"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave5"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave6"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave7"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave8"="wdmaud.drv"
"midi9"="wdmaud.drv"
"aux6"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer9"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave9"="wdmaud.drv"
"aux7"="wdmaud.drv"
"aux8"="wdmaud.drv"
"aux9"="wdmaud.drv"
"mixer2"="wdmaud.drv"
"wave2"="wdmaud.drv"
```